# find text sentence with regex where sentence starts and ends with special characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large xml file and every part starts with that sentence

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='Cp1252' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="TELEGRAMM"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Report xmlns="http:///Report"...
```

I wish to cut everything between

```
<? ?>
```

How can I do it with regular expression?

I tried

```
(<?xml version)(.*)(?=encoding="UTF-8"?>)
```

but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Try `(?s)<\?xml version.*?encoding="UTF-8"\?>`

Comment: `(?<=<\?).*(?=\?>)`

Comment: 1.) What do you want to cut? Remove both `<?xml version...` or from first to second, or second only? 2.) Leave the `<?`...`?>` around or remove? 3.) What about the lookahead in your pattern that matches ...`encoding="UTF-8"`? The lookahead would leave this part and not remove it. It looks confusing. As a start you need to escape `?` by backslash, else it's treated as quantifier. Experiment at [online tools like regex101](https://regex101.com/r/n5Ek8C/2).

Comment: I wish to cut all <?xml version='1.0'  encoding='Cp1252' ?>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="TELEGRAMM"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: So [first comment pattern](https://regex101.com/r/n5Ek8C/3) would work wouldn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex to replace with an empty string:

```
(?s)<\?xml version.*?encoding="UTF-8"\?>\s*
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - same as *`.` matches newline* option on - enables `.` to match line break chars
- `<\?xml version` - a `<?xml version` substring (note that `?` should be escaped to match a literal question mark)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `encoding="UTF-8"\?>` - `encoding="UTF-8"?>` substring.
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespace chars.

Settings/proof:

[image]